# php echo mysql array result in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, arrays

the below `function` is my `controller` code which is called by an `ajax` request:

```
function search_featured_candidates() {       
   $skills = $this->input->post('skills');
   $this->load->model('Featured_candidate', 'featured', TRUE);
   $result = $this->featured->get_featured_candidates_by_skills($skills);
   if ($result) {
      $str = "";
      foreach ($result as $row) {
          $str .= "Name: " . $row->candidate_name . "<br/>";
          $str .= "Exp: " . $row->experience . "<br/>";
          $str .= "Skills: " . $row->skills . "<hr/>";
      }
      $html = $str;
      echo json_encode(array('html' => $html, 'success' => TRUE));
      } else {
          $html = 'No Candidates Found!';
          echo json_encode(array('html' => $html, 'success' => FALSE));
      }
 }
```

my `view` code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#featured_candidates").on("change paste keyup", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>mypage/search_featured_candidates/",
            data: {skills: $(this).val()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success === true) {
                    $("#featured").html(data.html);
                } else {
                    $("#featured").html(data.html);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

 <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            <input type="text" style="width: 100%" 
             name="featured_candidates" id="featured_candidates" 
             placeholder="keyword / skills" title="Featured Candidates" 
             />
            <br/><hr/>
        </div>
        <div id="featured">
            <?php
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                echo "Name: " . $row->candidate_name . "<br/>";
                echo "Exp: " . $row->experience . "<br/>";
                echo "Skills: " . $row->skills . "<hr/>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

now i am trying to display the `result array` using `ajax` like i have displayed in my `view` code using `foreach`. so to display it using `ajax` i have concatenated the array in my controller method in `$str` but it is not working while when i updated my controller method to this:

```
 function search_featured_candidates() {       
   $skills = $this->input->post('skills');
   $html = $skills ;
   echo json_encode(array('html' => $html, 'success' => TRUE));
 }
```

it is working fine..any help or suggesttion would be a great help...thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake here

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "Name: " . $row->candidate_name . <br/>";
    echo "Exp: " . $row->experience . "<br/>";
    echo "Skills: " . $row->skills . "<hr/>";
}
```

You forgot the "

```
. $row->candidate_name . "<br/>";
                    //   ^ You forgot the "
```

Answer (score 0):

The formulation of your question makes it difficult to know where your problem really is. But from a quick look you normally have to set proper headers in order to output json formatted data with PHP.

Try adding this before you do your `echo`, maybe this solves your problem:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: You may have a problem with your `<br/>` and `<hr/>`. Try to replace them with `<br \/>` and `<hr \/>`. Have a look at the link posted in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11657161/2358063